# SQL select data from more than one table

Tags: 7, database

I've constructed a nice query in drupal 7:

```sql
SELECT og.label AS title, og.gid AS gid 
FROM og
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_group_category 
  ON og.etid = field_data_field_group_category.entity_id
WHERE ( (field_data_field_group_category.field_group_category_value IN  ('1')) )
ORDER BY title ASC
```

This works but actually I want to remove the WHERE clause and instead put field_data_field_group_cat.field_group_category_value in my result. But when I try:

```sql
SELECT og.label AS title
  , og.gid AS gid 
  field_data_field_group_category.field_group_category_value AS cat 
FROM  og, field_data_field_group_category
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_group_category
  ON og.etid = field_data_field_group_category.entity_id
ORDER BY title ASC
```

This won't work.. How do I get a value of another table in the result object?

Greetings!

Comment: Two things worth noting with this question.  One, nicely formatting queries will often reveal syntax and other errors.  PHP support multiline strings, so you don't have to worry about reformatting things.  Two, debugging queries inside a database tool (like MySQL Query browser) is much faster than trying to do this inside Drupal.

Answer (score 2):

You second query is incorrect because you have the table `field_data_field_group_category` two times, so it would generates duplicates and there's a missing coma in your SELECT clause. If you want your column in the result without filtering it, just put it in the SELECT clause and that's it.

```sql
SELECT og.label AS title
  , og.gid AS gid
  , field_data_field_group_category.field_group_category_value AS cat 
FROM og
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_group_category 
  ON og.etid = field_data_field_group_category.entity_id
ORDER BY title ASC
```